# update value only when changed

Tags: asp.net, sql

I had a good look around but couldn't quite find the answer to this one:
I got a Stored Procedure that updates around 30 Fields on a SQL SERVER 2008 Table. It's important for me that one of those Fields is only getting updated, if the value actually changed.

The Stored Procedure Snippet at the moment:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE test
@p_RoomNo int,
[RoomNo] = @p_RoomNo,
```

I tried changing it for that particular Column to COALESCE / ISNULL in the SET-Clause of the Procedure, but it still Updates that Column as well

```
[RoomNo] = COALESCE(@p_RoomNo,RoomNo),
[RoomNo] = ISNULL(@p_RoomNo,RoomNo),
```

both give me the same Output ...

Do you have any ideas how to NOT Update the Value on Server Side or do I have to put this on a .asp-Forum to change the Application to not pass on any values that are unchanged?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Have you considered using a SQL trigger on the database table?

Comment: that's why I want that particular field not to get updated, if the value didn't change - there's an update trigger on this table, that only fires when this fields updated ... unfortunately, it fires everytime ANY value is changed on that table ... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most proper place to check whether the values changed prior to storing the new value is in the asp side of the solution, not in the database. And then you can pass a parameter to the stored procedure.

In the procedure, base on that parameter, you decide whether you should change the value or not.

**Edit:** Suppose you have a server control of the [HiddenField type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx).

```
Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (IsPostBack) {
        if (myTextBoxIWannaCheckForChanges.Text != myHiddenField.Value) {
            // The value has changed.
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will check for changes during the page load. You could also use that kind of logic while handling a button click (if you do so, you don't have to check for a PostBack). Like this:

```
foo_clicked (object sender, EventArgs args) {
    SqlCommand command = // ...snip
    // ... set everything you need for your command.
    bool changed = (myTextBoxIWannaCheckForChanges.Text != myHiddenField.Value);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@changed", changed);
    // ... finally let the command execute.
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions on this side ? I am not really that much into .asp and it's third party software - any suggestions where to look for restricting Save-Actions on ButtonClick Stuff would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm rusty with legacy ASP, sorry. If it were ASP.NET, you could compare the values of fields between posts to see whether they have changed.

Comment: You could also try some javascript and jQuery. `$("id").change(function)` will cause said function to be called only when the value of the element with the referred id has its value changed.

Comment: Thanks @Renan ... it is actually ASP.NET, need some time to go through the structure though - seeing it's 3rd Party I am not so sure where to look at :) That's why I looked at trying it server side ...

Comment: In that case I have retagged the question. Use a server control of the Hidden type and store the same value as the one in the control which you want to validate. In the page_load event, in a `if (IsPostBack)` block, compare the value of the hidden field with that of the other control. If they're not the same, then the value has changed.

Comment: I look into it, but I really am not .asp familiar, what sort of code would you need out of the .asp-application to give me an idea of how to construct this ?

Comment: I've edited the answer for a starter on how to do it. It's up to you to learn some ADO.NET now. Good practice and good coding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all replies ... 
Changing the Front-End-Application was no option in the end, because changes wouldn't reflect in Future Versions seeing that it's 3rd Party.
I tried most options to alter the SProc but either ran into not getting the desired Field Value updated at all (even when the Value changed) or updating all the times. I decided to look more into the problem from the other side (why I wanted this field not to be updated when the Value didn't change, which was an Update-Trigger, that should only fire when the Value of that Field actually changed.

In the end, the solution was very simple:

Seeing that the

```
IF UPDATE (RoomNo)
```

in the Trigger doesn't really compare the Value of the Field but merely if there's an Update called, I simply had to add the comparison via INSERTED and DELETED, so I added the join with DELETED, set my Where Clause on it and it works :)

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[UpdateDepartDate]
on [dbo].[Customer]
for update 
As 
Begin 
if update (RoomNo) 
Begin 
UPDATE Customer
SET [DepartDate] = null
FROM  Rooms r
INNER JOIN Customer cu
ON cu.[RoomNo] = r.[Room_ID]
Join INSERTED INS
ON cu.[CU_ID] = INS.[CU_ID]
join Deleted Del 
ON INS.[CU_ID] = DEL.[CU_ID]
WHERE INS.[RoomNo] <> DEL.[RoomNo]
END
END
```

Thought I post it here for anyone interested :) 
Thanks again everyone for your help